How to make listview.builder support landscape scrolling in flutter
How to make listview.builder support landscape scrolling in flutter
 ListView.builder(
                    itemExtent: 60,
                    itemCount: controller.lotQueryList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (c, i) {
})

help me

There's a property in it, scrollDirection. Here how you can use this below:
ListView.builder( scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, //also there is option for Axis.vertical ///other items )

Here is the code to achieve landscape scrolling in Column Widget:
Column(
    children: [
      //First ListView
      ListView.builder(
          itemExtent: 60,
          itemCount: controller.lotQueryList.length,
          //ADD THIS
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (c, i) {
          // Your Widget
            return Container();
          }),


       //Second ListView
          ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 60,
              itemCount: controller.lotQueryList.length,
              //ADD THIS
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (c, i) {
              // Your Widget
                return Container();
              })
        ],
      ),

Here is a Full Example of What you want
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 50,
              left: 20,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: const Text(
              "First Lsitview",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 2),
            height: 30,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 50,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "I am index$index",
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 26,
              left: 20,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: const Text(
              "Second Lsitview",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 2),
            height: 30,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 50,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "I am index$index",
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 26,
              left: 20,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: const Text(
              "Third Lsitview",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 2),
            height: 30,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 50,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "I am index$index",
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Happy Coding :)

What I mean is how to scroll outside listview.builder so that listview.builder supports both horizontal and vertical scrolling

So you want to have multiple horizontal listviews (right to left) and scroll listviews up to down?

我需要一个竖向的listview.builder，但又希望这个list 可以横向滚动

I got it bro✅ Check my edited answer again
